# Navigation bar hover effects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this little website i'm trying to write and I've got this buggingly bugging problem. Basically I have a navigation bar, and I want the dropdown to fade in when you hover onto the main word on the navigation bar. I've tried many ways, it doesn't seem to affect anything at all. I've looked up on different pages, but no matter how I try and rig it up, it still doesn't seem to want to work.

My first attempt with CSS:

```js
document.getElementById("server").onmouseover = function() {
  serverMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("server").onmouseout = function() {
  serverMouseOut()
};

function serverMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "block";
}

function serverMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseover = function() {
  serverMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseout = function() {
  serverMouseOut()
};

function serverMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "block";
}

function serverMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(21, 14, 43);
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogomainbox:hover {
  width: 12vw;
}

#gigalogo {
  width: 26vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
  padding: 0;
}

#steamlogomainbox {
  width: 10.5vw;
  height: 7vw;
  float: right;
  background-color: #0B0D16;
  /*000c21*/
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin: 0.2vw -1vw 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogo {
  padding: 0.7vw 0 0 3vw;
  height: 5.6vw;
}

#navbarbox {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  padding: 0vw 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar,
#navbar ul {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar span {
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}

#navbar li {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vw 3.95vw 1vw 3.95vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  font-family: Jura;
  height: 2.5vw;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

#serverdropdownbox {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 0;
}

#serverdropdowncontent {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16vw;
  margin: 1vw 0 0 10.1vw;
}

#server:hover #serverdropdowncontent li {
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

#serverdropdowncontent li {
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-color: white;
}

.menugradient {
  backround: darkblue;
}

#server {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" />
</head>

<body>


  <!--Giga logo, top left-->
  <img id="gigalogo" src="images/gigalogo.png">

  <!--Steam logo, top right-->
  <div id="steamlogomainbox">
    <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
  </div>

  <!--navigation barrrrrr-->
  <div id="navbarbox">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <a href="default.html">
        <li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="servers.html">
        <li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="community.html">
        <li id="community"><span>Community</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="store.html">
        <li id="store"><span>Store</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="downloads.html">
        <li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="serverdropdownbox">
    <ul id="serverdropdowncontent">
      <a href="serverlist.html">
        <li id="serverdropdownli">Server List</li>
      </a>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">GigaDB</li>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">CS:GO</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

My second attempt with JS:

```js
document.getElementById("server").onmouseover = function() {
  serverMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("server").onmouseout = function() {
  serverMouseOut()
};

function serverMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("serverdropdowncontent").style.transition = "opacity 2s ease-in"
  document.getElementById("serverdropdowncontent").style.opacity = "1"
  document.getElementById("serverdropdowncontent").style.WebkitTransition = "opacity 2s ease-in"
  document.getElementById("serverdropdowncontent").style.WebkitOpacity = "1"
}

function serverMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseover = function() {
  serverMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseout = function() {
  serverMouseOut()
};

function serverMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "block";
}

function serverMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(21, 14, 43);
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogomainbox:hover {
  width: 12vw;
}

#gigalogo {
  width: 26vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
  padding: 0;
}

#steamlogomainbox {
  width: 10.5vw;
  height: 7vw;
  float: right;
  background-color: #0B0D16;
  /*000c21*/
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin: 0.2vw -1vw 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogo {
  padding: 0.7vw 0 0 3vw;
  height: 5.6vw;
}

#navbarbox {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  padding: 0vw 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar,
#navbar ul {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar span {
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}

#navbar li {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vw 3.95vw 1vw 3.95vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  font-family: Jura;
  height: 2.5vw;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

#serverdropdownbox {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 0;
}

#serverdropdowncontent {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16vw;
  margin: 1vw 0 0 10.1vw;
}

#serverdropdowncontent li {
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-color: white;
}

#server {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" />
  <link href="css/mainframe.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
  <link href="css/navbar.css" type="text/css" rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>


  <!--Giga logo, top left-->
  <img id="gigalogo" src="images/gigalogo.png">

  <!--Steam logo, top right-->
  <div id="steamlogomainbox">
    <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
  </div>

  <!--navigation barrrrrr-->
  <div id="navbarbox">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <a href="default.html">
        <li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="servers.html">
        <li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="community.html">
        <li id="community"><span>Community</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="store.html">
        <li id="store"><span>Store</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="downloads.html">
        <li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="serverdropdownbox">
    <ul id="serverdropdowncontent">
      <a href="serverlist.html">
        <li id="serverdropdownli">Server List</li>
      </a>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">GigaDB</li>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">CS:GO</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Sorry I have very very basic understanding of JS, I'm sure there's a direct and easier way i've completely missed out on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. I have made some changes in CSS and JS part. follow it

```js
document.getElementById("server").onmouseover = function() {
  serverMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("server").onmouseout = function() {
  serverMouseOut()
};

function serverMouseOver() {
 //add the corresponding classes for the effect
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className+="animated fadeIn";
}

function serverMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className+="animated fadeOut";
}
```

```css
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(21, 14, 43);
  background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogomainbox:hover {
  width: 12vw;
}

#gigalogo {
  width: 26vw;
  height: 8vw;
  margin: 0 0 0 2vw;
  padding: 0;
}

#steamlogomainbox {
  width: 10.5vw;
  height: 7vw;
  float: right;
  background-color: #0B0D16;
  /*000c21*/
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin: 0.2vw -1vw 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steamlogo {
  padding: 0.7vw 0 0 3vw;
  height: 5.6vw;
}

#navbarbox {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  padding: 0vw 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar,
#navbar ul {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar span {
  height: 3.5vw;
  display: block;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
}

#navbar li {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1vw 3.95vw 1vw 3.95vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  font-family: Jura;
  height: 2.5vw;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}

#serverdropdownbox {
  opacity : 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  width: 0;
}

#serverdropdowncontent {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 16vw;
  margin: 1vw 0 0 10.1vw;
}


#serverdropdowncontent li {
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-color: white;
}

.menugradient {
  backround: darkblue;
}

#server {
  background-color: blue;
}




.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}


@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<!--Giga logo, top left-->
  <img id="gigalogo" src="images/gigalogo.png">

  <!--Steam logo, top right-->
  <div id="steamlogomainbox">
    <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
  </div>

  <!--navigation barrrrrr-->
  <div id="navbarbox">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <a href="default.html">
        <li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="servers.html">
        <li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="community.html">
        <li id="community"><span>Community</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="store.html">
        <li id="store"><span>Store</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="downloads.html">
        <li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html">
        <li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="serverdropdownbox">
    <ul id="serverdropdowncontent">
      <a href="serverlist.html">
        <li id="serverdropdownli">Server List</li>
      </a>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">GigaDB</li>
      <li id="serverdropdownli">CS:GO</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Remove this from your css

```
#server:hover #serverdropdowncontent li {
transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That looks a lot neater than what I have! Thank you! I'll try that out :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried adding your code on to my existing code, but I still can't get it to work. May I know if you have changed any small details I might have missed out on? @Altair827

Comment: I copied the whole chunk of the CSS and JS you added, didn't work for me.

Comment: I only edited the CSS and the JS code. If you copied and pasted it correctly, it should work.

Comment: My gosh, i just found the problem after an intense battle with finding it. Sorry for the trouble...the mistake I made was this: "..function() {fadeIn};" . I didn't add the () at the end of the fadeIn. How is this so important :c

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want it to change background color when you hover over it, this CSS solution SHOULD do it

```
.navbar:hover li {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```